# angular 2 file works directly directly but not via nodejs express file

Tags: node.js, angular

I am starting a MEA2N app, and built a small express server running on port 3000.
The angular app runs on port 4200. If I open localhost 3000 I see 'loading...' ergo the app does not run. While if I open localhost 4000 I get 'app working'. Does anybody know how this might happen?

server.js is very standard:

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

server.js is running in root folder.
angular app is root/src/indxex.html and root/src/app/

Comment: Please include your folder structure and your app.js

Answer (score 0):

If `server.js` is in `root` folder and angular app is on `root/src/index.html`

then

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

should be

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/src')));
```

Comment: you are totally correct. I changed that part already, unfortunately still no effect. Opening localhost 4200 works. Opening localhost 3000 does not

Comment: @Mihaly any errors? check the network tab on chrome developer tools to see if it can find index.html

Comment: No none unfortunately.